# Shutdown with terminal on rising edge of GPIO input

Tags: python, terminal, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to trigger my Raspberry Pi to shutdown on the rising edge of GPIO #4. I ultimately want to auto run this script on startup.

My python code is in file test1.py @ /home/pi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Starting")
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING)
def my_callback(x):
    print("Event Triggered")
    command = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now"
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
    x=1

GPIO.add_event_callback(4,my_callback)
print("End")
```

My terminal code is

```
sudo python test1.py
```

My output is

```
Starting
End
```

When I enter the above python code into Python shell, I get the above output and upon triggering GPIO4,  it shuts down.

When I call it from the Terminal I get the above outputs but upon triggering GPIO4 nothing happens.

What am I missing so this will work from the terminal screen?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be in `GPIO.BOARD` mode when referencing to the pin?

Comment: I should be referencing the right pin because the code functions properly when called from python. would this need changed when calling the file test1.py from the terminal?

Comment: Okay you're right, I was just wondering; have no pi here atm. Does the code even wait for a press if you execute it from the terminal or does it exit directly?

Comment: In terminal  when I enter "sudo python test1.py" , it prints
     Starting, End, and then the "pi@raspberrypi:~ $".

Comment: Ok so it seems like you have to initiate a mainloop to keep the script running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems to exit directly without waiting for an event. You may want to use a function that blocks the script until an event happens.

```
if GPIO.wait_for_edge(4,GPIO.RISING):
    my_callback()
```

at the end of the program will block the thread until an edge is detected. You don't seem to need `x` in the function so I just omitted it. There is also no need for `GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING)`  and `GPIO.add_event_callback(4,my_callback)` with this change

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, so others know it's solved ;)